# Discord.js V13 404 not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Trying to get a user id with regex, and then sending them a dm. Not working at all. The args will be like !DM @usermention.

```js
const { MessageMentions: { USERS_PATTERN } } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "DM",
    description: "Will DM given author",
    async run(message, args, client) {
        const matches = String(args).match(USERS_PATTERN);

        if (!matches) return;

        const id = matches[1];

        client.users.fetch(id).then(dm => {
            dm.send("Hello");
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: @skara9 Thanks a lot! That seems to have done the trick. No errors are showing up. But it's still not sending dms. Can you help me out with that too please?

Comment: Do you have the required intents? What are they?

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the array to a string before matching, which should work fine but I'm not sure it's what you want.

Then you are getting the second match with `matches[1]` instead of the first one.

And then you are using the match, formatted as `<@XXXXXXXX>` as an id, which is supposed to be numerical.

I would suggest replacing all that with simply:

```js
async run(message, args, client) {
    message.mentions.users.first().send('Hello');
}
```

this gets the first user mention in the message and dms the user 'Hello'